# Help! 2005 Mazda 3 brakes

Tags: brakes

I noticed recently that my brake goes soft and almost to the floor. Several months ago I had new brakes put on and I just took it in again to bleed the brakes. 
I just picked up the car and the brakes feel the same.  Any ideas?
The mechanic noticed that there was hardly any oil in the car. It was puzzling because in October I just had the oil changed.  Thank you!

Comment: You have two unrelated issues. You should create two questions to cover. Also, give us some more details, like what does "brakes done" mean to you, and have you looked/seen oil where the car sits. Any other pertinent details. As your question is, there's a plethora of things which could be going on. Help us help you diagnose your issues.

Answer (score 1):

A vehicle fitted with a modern brake servo, as the Mazda 3 would have 'servo travel'. To determine how much travel you have: Engine off, pump the brake several times until it is hard and will not increase its pedal height anymore, press the brake pedal and hold it pressed, car in neutral start the engine still holding the brake pedal down with your foot. You will find the brake pedal travels down an amount. This is your servo working as it should. Is there any great differance in brake travel when operating the brake whilst driving, or is it about the same? If it is about the same then you now know it is your servo's operation giving you its travel. But if the travel is greater in use you have a problem and the brake system needs to be pressure tested, and a careful examination of its hoses undertaken by a competent mechanic. As for the low oil level, was it fully filled up on the oil change? Do you have blue smoke out of the exhaust? Sump plug washer and oil filter seal good? The longer it is before the low oil level is noticed to be low the harder it would be to say why the oil level was found to be low.